# Issue with Queries on WCF and SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, wcf

Here is my scenario: I have a Silverlight application that connects to a WCF service. Application uses windows authentication, WCF service connects to SQL Server database using an id that has proper access to database. This all works fine on development server, when I move the application to Test server, ONLY some of the queries return proper results. For some queries, it prompts with Windows Security dialog. I am not sure what is prompting this. If there is an issue with connection with SQL Server then none of the queries would work, appreciate any feedback. Thanks Jay

Comment: I don't think you will ever see a network credential prompt for database credentials when being routed through a web service. The prompt is more than likely your because your ticket has expired in your web app and you are using windows auth.

Comment: @lrb : Exactly one can not achieve the strong security with the windows authentication.

Comment: The follwing addtion in web.config of WCF service resolved the issue. <serviceBehaviors> <behavior name="ServiceBehavior"> <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/> </behavior> </serviceBehaviors>

Answer (score 0):

In Web.config of WCF service:

```
    <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
            <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
            </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
```